# Refresh 'Related' grid on form in MSCRM 2011

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

On a form in MS CRM 2011, there is a section Related on the left side.
In the section, there are entities which are related to the current one (1:N and N:N relations).

I'd like to refresh a grid displaying related records by Javascript (grid in Related section, not on a form).

Earlier, I used:

```js
   document.getElementById('area'+relationName+'Frame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('crmGrid_'+relationName).Refresh();
```

However, after Rollup 12, this code stopped working.

I tried another code:

```js
 var iframe = document.getElementById('area'+relationName+'Frame');
 iframe.src = iframe.src
```

It refreshes a grid, but the header of the grid (view selector and search) disappears. It works, but it's not optimal.

Is there some better way to do it?

I think there is no supported way of customization; but, it would be still useful to have working solution.

Answer (score 0):

for me the

```
document.getElementById('area'+relationName+'Frame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('crmGrid_'+relationName).control.refresh();
```

works just fine, but you have to be sure that the document that the control is located in, is already fully loaded. You have to run your refresh() call from a 'onload' or 'ready' event handler of the parent document.